# Should I use #ifndef Q_MOC_RUN as much a possible?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, include, moc

I have a Qt/C++ project that uses Boost library, and I see Boost headers are included like this:

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#endif
```

I read that if you don't do this, MOC might cause problems.

The question is, shouldn't I then use this guard for including all other headers that definitely don't contain Q_OBJECT marco? Standard library headers for example, and other non-Qt libraries? Wouldn't it save a lot of time when MOC preprocessor runs?

Comment: I'd say: do it only if necessary. If "moc causes problems", the compiler usually tells you.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, thanks for the reply! Why not all the time though to save build time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the topic [Qt5 moc error in combination with boost](https://forum.qt.io/topic/22458/semi-solved-qt5-moc-error-in-combination-with-boost/12):

> First, this is a known MOC issue. **The MOC can't expand some of the
>   macros used in the Boost library.** I believe the reason Qt 4.8 works is
>   that a workaround for specific Boost macro definitions was added to
>   the MOC configuration for that version.
>
> What you need to do to work around this issue: As stated above, use
>   Q_MOC_RUN to comment out problematic headers. **You ONLY need to use
>   Q_MOC_RUN in files that produce a moc** file (e.g. myheader.h will
>   produce moc_myheader.cpp). You can limit the hack to just those files.
>   So you don't need to #ifndef all usages of Boost headers in your
>   project which limits the pain of implementing this solution quite a
>   bit.

Seems this issue was fixed quite a long time ago, so whether you don't have any problems and don't need to support old versions of Qt, you may won't add this macro to your future code.